# multiple socksproxies bridged to vpn tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, route

I've bought vpn access from a vpn provider. I'm able to have 5 concurrent vpn sessions within the subscription.

I'm trying to do following setup:

1..n socks-proxy -> 1..n openvpn client tunnels to (different) serverlocations.

You can specify the external interface in the (dante) socksproxy server.
This works quite well if I do the setup for 1 vpn tunnel.

If I specify more I ran into the issue that multiple default gateway's aren't allowed.
I've tried to play with the metric value in the routes without any success.

So a question in general: Is it possible to have multiple vpn tunnels and they should route all traffic (no subnet should be specified)?

The only "workaround" I see is to deploy a docker container for every vpn tunnel I set up.

Are there any other tips?